# Programmatically modify Firewall rules in Windows Server 2008 R2

Tags: .net, powershell, windows-firewall, windows-firewall-api

I want be able to programmatically enable, disable, create firewall rules in Windows Server 2008 R2.
What is the object model to modify the firewall rules from .Net/PowerShell?

Answer (score 0):

There is probably a WMI set of classes for this but I wanted to point out that you can use the existing command line utility netsh.exe from PowerShell.  Execute:

```
netsh firewall /?
```

To see its options.

Comment: Nope, I've never seen a WMI API, but I've been wrong (many) times before.

Comment: Wow and I thought WMI supported everything including the kitchen sink.  :-)

Answer (score 0):

There's also using COM:

```
$fw=new-object -com hnetcfg.fwmgr
```