# Is there any API for changing firewall rules on Windows Server 2008?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, firewall

There seems to be a set of [commands to programatically modify Firewall rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2231688/programmatically-modify-firewall-rules-in-windows-server-2008-r2) on Windows Server 2008. I have an app that handles a set of sockets, and from time to time it gets a DDoS.

I want to block some IP addresses from receiving the SYN-ACK on the TCP handshake. How can I do that from C++ in MS Visual C++?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Microsoft only published VB script samples,

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366415%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

You have to translate them to C++ manually if you don't want to call netsh command in your applications.

Generally speaking, there are a few COM objects you can use, such as HNetCfg.FwMgr. The VB script samples show how to use them properly.

Other references:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366449%28v=vs.85%29.aspx